# How to use 2 Webbrowser controls to use different cache/sessions

Tags: vb.net

I am using 2 different webbrowser controls in 2 different forms. 
I open a page (www.dropbox.com/login) and login to the application.
When trying to open the same page in another webbrowser control on a different form, the application goes to the post login page, that is the application is already logged in. 
How can i avoid this and do something such that both the webbrowser controls i have to login individually?

Answer (score 0):

Prior to IE8 you could call [InternetSetOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385114%28VS.85%29.aspx) to end the session for that instance.

I don't think this is possible in IE8 and newer. Instances of the webbrowser control and Internet Explorer all share the same sessions and cookies.